# $ is not defined before DOMContentLoaded - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, domcontentloaded

the first statement in a js file I have is

```
$(document).on("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
   $(document.body).on('beforeinsert', onBeforeInsert);
   $(document.body).on('afterinsert', onAfterInsert);
   $(document.body).on('wait', onWait);
   $(window).on('load', onLoad);
});
```

but when I use firebug it tells me that "$ is not defined". Elsewhere in the file everything works as expected. In fact if I change the first line to

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
```

everything also works fine. I don't want to do this because I want to be able to get cross browser compatibility.

Comment: Does that code come after the `<script>` tag that imports jQuery?

Comment: This wouldn't fix your problem, but just use `$(document).ready(function () {});` instead of looking for the `DOMContentLoaded` event - it will be more compatible across browsers

Comment: nope, and that fixed my issue

Comment: @karthikr I think he means using `$(document).ready` INSTEAD of listening on `$(document)` for a `DOMContentLoaded` event, which is correct.

Comment: @karthikr I don't know what you mean. If this code is in the `<head>`, `document.body` won't be found, and it should wait for the DOM to be ready, using `.ready()`. Nonetheless - listening for the `DOMContentLoaded` event is silly to do when you have jQuery to do it for you in a more reliable way. And if the code is in the `<body>`, then waiting for the DOM to be ready is unnecessary anyways, unless the OP **needs** to make sure the DOM is ready before any of the new bound events should be able to be called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error message because your script runs before `$` is defined.

To fix it, make sure jQuery is loaded before running that script.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you haven't included the JQuery JS file before attempting to use JQuery. Remember that browsers render the page top to bottom so add the reference to the Jquery JS file to the top of the page.

Comment: The reference to the jQuery library doesn't need to be (and should not be) at the top of the page, just before any script that requires jQuery.

Comment: or, add it to the bottom, but make sure anything that needs it comes after it. If it's at the bottom, you don't even need a DOMContentLoaded event listener.

Answer (score 0):

Your js is running before jquery loads. Try:

1 - Reference jquery at page header, before defining this script

2 - use $( [...] ):

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
       $(document.body).on('beforeinsert', onBeforeInsert);
       $(document.body).on('afterinsert', onAfterInsert);
       $(document.body).on('wait', onWait);
       $(window).on('load', onLoad);
    });
});
```